# Fixing Content within 2 Columns

Tags: html, css

I am trying to generate a PDF from HTML which I have been able to do but I am having issues setting the HTML columns properly.

I have 2 columns named **a** and **b** see code:

```
.a{
    background: red;
    width: 24%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
  }

 .b{
    background: blue;
    width: 74%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
  }
```

Column A would contain 5 icons and Column B would contain Text, Heading etc. The **issue I am having** is that the images in Columns A move based on the amount of data entered in Column B and vice versa.

I want to fix the content in both columns so no matter how much text is entered in Column B the icons stay fixed.

The image below shows the output I am getting:

**Large Quantity of Text**

[image]

**Small Quantity of Text**

[image]

Apologies if I have not explained properly, please let me know and I'll try and explain better.

Comment: Update ur html code r working fiddle to check.

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/JJMNNb

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yup thats it! Thank you! If you put that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `inline-block` elements have `vertical-align: baseline`. If you want the columns to be aligned at the top, use `vertical-align: top` on the columns.

```css
.a {
  background: red;
  width: 25%; 
}

.b {
  background: blue;
  width: 75%;
}

.a, .b {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg"><img
    src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg">
</div><!--
--><div class="b">Column A would contain 5 icons and Column B would contain Text, Heading etc. The issue I am having is that the images in Columns A move based on the amount of data entered in Column B and vice versa.

  <br>Column A would contain 5 icons and Column B would contain Text, Heading etc. The issue I am having is that the images in Columns A move based on the amount of data entered in Column B and vice versa.

  <br>Column A would contain 5 icons and Column B would contain Text, Heading etc. The issue I am having is that the images in Columns A move based on the amount of data entered in Column B and vice versa.

  <br>Column A would contain 5 icons and Column B would contain Text, Heading etc. The issue I am having is that the images in Columns A move based on the amount of data entered in Column B and vice versa.

  <br>Column A would contain 5 icons and Column B would contain Text, Heading etc. The issue I am having is that the images in Columns A move based on the amount of data entered in Column B and vice versa.

  <br>Column A would contain 5 icons and Column B would contain Text, Heading etc. The issue I am having is that the images in Columns A move based on the amount of data entered in Column B and vice versa.

  <br>Column A would contain 5 icons and Column B would contain Text, Heading etc. The issue I am having is that the images in Columns A move based on the amount of data entered in Column B and vice versa.

  <br>Column A would contain 5 icons and Column B would contain Text, Heading etc. The issue I am having is that the images in Columns A move based on the amount of data entered in Column B and vice versa.

  <br>Column A would contain 5 icons and Column B would contain Text, Heading etc. The issue I am having is that the images in Columns A move based on the amount of data entered in Column B and vice versa.

  <br>
</div>
```